# iOs SDK: Download protected file from server

Tags: php, ios, file, .htaccess, download

I am currently working on something like an own cloud service (but without using owncloud) and I am also developing an app for it.
Private files on my server are in a folder which is protected by a .htaccess file. So you can't access the files with a direct link. There's a `get_file.php?file=filename` which checks if the user is logged in and then uses `readfile()` from php. My problem is that if I try to download a file like this in my iOs App with a progress bar (and `NSURLConnection` delegation methods), the result is, the App downloads the get_file.php file itself. I already tried some other ways. For example if I remove the `$_SESSION` check in the `get_file.php`, I just get an empty `.html` file for download. 
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!
Vincent

Comment: Have you properly configured the file type on the server so it is run as php instead of served as a file download?

Comment: If I open up get_file.php in a browser on my mac, it works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it on my own, had to configure the header information correctly.The Content-Type was set to form instead of force-download.